# Laravel second DB connection select and filter by foreign key value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I have this situation:

I use a second DB in my laravel application. I use this method to connect to it and modify/select data:

```
$result = DB::connection('mysql_live')->table('users_album')
->where('isApprove', 'Pending')->count();
```

I have a `users` table and a user can have many album images, so I have a `users_album` table. Users can be either `active` or `inactive`.

The table `users_album` has a column `users_id`, so I know which album image belongs to which user.

**Now I need to count all album images, which belong to users, who are active**

I could ofc. select all users, who are active and put their id's into an array and then filter with `->whereIn`:

```
$activeUsers = DB::connection('mysql_live')->table('users')
->where('active', '!=', 'inactive')->pluck('id')->toArray();

$result = DB::connection('mysql_live')->table('users_album')->where('isApprove', 'Pending')
->whereIn('user_id', $activeUsers)->count();
```

But this takes super long and fails if I select the whole dataset, so obviously its not the way to go.

In pseudocode I need something like this:

```
$result = DB::connection('mysql_live')->table('users_album')->where('isApprove', 'Pending')
->where(USER WITH ID USER_ID IS ACTIVE)->count();
```

**EDIT:**

Both tables `users` and `users_album` are stored in the same DB and have a relation.

I am mentioning the second DB because I dont use eloquent laravel style for this, f.e. I cant do: `UserAlbum::where('isApprove', 'Pending')->count();`

**EDIT**

I found a "hacky" solution to do this, but its hard to believe it has to be done like this:

```
$result_ = array_unique(DB::connection('mysql_live')->table('users_album')->where('isApprove', 'Pending')->pluck('user_id')->toArray());
$users = array_unique(DB::connection('mysql_live')->table('users')->whereIn('id', $result_)->where('active', '!=', 'inactive')->pluck('id')->toArray());
$result = DB::connection('mysql_live')->table('users_album')->where('isApprove', 'Pending')->whereIn('user_id', $users)->count();
```

Step one: I extract all user_id's from album images.

Step two: I select only users, where the id is in the array of previously extracted id's, addtionaly I filter by the active column and extract the id's again.

Step three: Now I can count the album_images of active users, by additionaly filtering the count query with the previously extracted array of active users.

Comment: And what's your question? How would you do so if everything were stored in the first database? What about using proper indices?

Comment: @Nico Haase The things are stored in the same DB

Comment: @Nico Haase The question is: I need to count all album images, which belong to users, who are active

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with a join: Something like:

```
$activeUsers = DB::connection('mysql_live')->table('users_album')->join('users','users.id','=','users_album.users_id')
->where('users.active', '!=', 'inactive')->count();
```

You should watch your indexes. users_id is not good - user_id would be correct...

EDIT: Example that this is working perfectly well!
[image: Frontend Example]

[image: Backend Code]

Comment: This does not work. I assume because I use a secondary connection, which does not use eloquent. The relation is defined in the DB, but not in the app. For example, your solution would work if I had: `->hasMany('AlbumImage');` and `->belongsTo('User');`

Comment: It doesn't matter that there is no defined realtion as the relation is specifically pointed in the join. This works perfectly well - just tried it without any problems!
Have you tried it? I don't think so... If you did - what's the error you are getting? I updated my answer with two pictures where you can see that it is working

Comment: I tried it and it counted way too much entries. In my case the result should be 171. But it counts over 200k entries. I will give it a second shot and let you know. Thanks for your time.

Comment: ok - it should work as intended. Maybe there's a problem with the foreign key in the db?

Comment: I had time now to look at it again. I was too quick to discard your solution, because I have a good workaround. This was missing: `->where('users_album.isApprove', 'Pending')`. Thanks!